# Can i make a "streaming" video without using FMS?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, flash-media-server

Is it possible to create a streaming video without using FMS. Overall, my main question is, if it's possible to stream a video ( kept on server) to stream without using any technology ?

Comment: I mean.. without using additional technologies like Flash Media Server. Or whatever else (not even Windows Media Server as CarlF mentioned) used in addition to basic technologies like html,php,flash etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is yes: you can pass just an url to `.flv` or `.mp4` file to [`NetStream.play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play%28%29)

Comment: This is not correct. You aren't strictly "streaming" video using this call unless it is hosted on a streaming server. You can *play* it, but (for instance) seeking within the stream will not work as it would on a true stream. That is, the video file will progressively download and you will only be able to seek within the portion which is downloaded, unless it is hosted on a streaming server.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is at best ambiguous. If I understand correctly, yes, you can stream video without Flash Media Server, but you will need some kind of streaming media server, which can be anything from Windows Media Services to the free, Free, cross-platform and very low-overhead ffmpeg.

Details about which media server to use really belong on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: ya.. without using any server. Like say using a server side script PHP, that can extract stream bit by bit and broadcast at client side ?

Comment: @wvxvw, actually ffmpeg is also a streaming server. Check it out. VLC is both a media player and streaming server. Lots of FLOSS is like that.